# XDMP_DFBUFWRITE, When do we get this error?

Tags: marklogic

These errors have occurred on replica forests.

> Alert: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in checkpoint of forest xyz-forest-008:
>   XDMP-DFBUFWRITE: Data Frame buffered write error: invalid word count,
>   words: 105008327, max: 67188742, Forest xyz-forest-008

Does anyone know what is the scenario where I can get these errors ?